# Function to split and cut the string and print in PHP

Tags: php

I want to know the function that can perform the following operation

$str = "uploads/file/file1.jpg";

i want to slash the initial of the string uploads/file/ and just want to return file1.jpg as value.

i tried using str_replace(),

```
$str = "uploads/file/file1.jpg";

$str2 = str_replace("uploads/file"," ", $str);

echo $str;
```

this is not working, where i am going wrong?

EDIT : Silly me i  was not noticing that i was trying to echo $str, sorry for this. it is working for me now.

BTW i want to know which method is better the above one or the basename();

Comment: If you can, always go with built-in methods. So in this case `basename()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`basename()`](http://www.php.net/basename): It is designed specifically to get the file name part out of a path.

```
$str2 = basename("uploads/file/file1.jpg");  // Will return file1.jpg
```

Also interesting (although not necessary in this examle) is [`pathinfo()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) which splits a string into four components: Directory, base name, file name, and extension.

The equivalent to split URLs into their components is [`parse_url()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

Comment: +1 thank you for that info Pekka, you are always there to help me :)

Comment: Seeing as I've been so graciously upvoted, I feel compelled to add some more info :)

Answer (score 1):

Use basename:

```
$path = "/home/httpd/html/index.php";
$file = basename($path);        // $file is set to "index.php"
$file = basename($path, ".php"); // $file is set to "index"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
substr($str, strrpos($str, "/"))
```

Or if you want to strip uploads/file only

```
substr($str, strlen("uploads/file"))
```